# How to traverse memory for the Fibonacci sequence in ARM assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, fibonacci

I must write the following function in its own assembly file:
`void fillFibonacciArray(int *array, int n);` The function writes into the array the first n Fibonacci numbers, i.e., each element is the sum of the prior two elements.

What I have so far:

```
fillFibonacciArray:
        cmp r1, 0
        beq allDone

        mov r6, 1
        str r6, [r0]            @ Arr[0] = 1
        cmp r1, 1
        beq allDone

        mov r6, 1
        str r6, [r0, 4]         @ Arr[1] = 1
        cmp r1, 2
        beq allDone
        mov r4, 3               @ int i = 3


loop:
        ldr r2, [r0, -4]        @ Arr[i-2]
        add r5, r2, r0      @ Arr[i-2] + Arr[i-1]
        mov r6, r5              
        str r6, [r0, 4]         @ Arr[i] = Arr[i-2] + Arr[i-1]

        add r4, r4, 1           @ i++
        cmp r4, r1              @ i < n?? branch to loop if it is
        blt loop

        b allDone

allDone:
       bx lr
```

My confusion begins with accessing the previous two values. Do I use logical shifting to move around the array or is offsetting capable of accomplish this task? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You use bit-shifts to access different parts of a word that's already in a register.  When you want a whole different `int` in an array, you just use offsets in an `ldr`, like you're doing with `ldr r2, [r0, -4]` to access the `int` before the point pointed-to by `r0`.  (An `int` is 4 bytes.)  Of course, you don't need to reload, you can just keep the current and previous value in registers.  `x += y;`  / `y += x;` is really efficient if you're unrolling the loop by 2.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point on not reloading haha. Also, another quick question, when I do ```ldr r2, [r0, -4]```to save the previous value, am I changing the address of r0, or does it stay at the current top of the array? Thank you!

Comment: `ldr` is a load from memory, not "saving" the previous value.  Re: what ARM addressing mode syntax means: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210602-00/?p=105271  / https://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/addressing.html or google `arm addressing modes`.